# Sqlite where clause with multiple values in select statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am trying a sqlite select query statement as below:

```
SELECT IndicatorText 
FROM Table 
where IndicatorID in('13','25','64','52','13','25','328')
      AND RubricID in('1','1','1','1','1','1','6')
```

This gives an output but the duplicate values are not displayed. I want to display all the values of IndicatorText even though it is duplicate.

Please help me with this query.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that should display your duplicates. There's the option of using a `DISTINCT` or `ALL` keyword after `SELECT` - but `ALL` is default, so should have the same effect here. Check you're reading all the answers out your table, and not just the first? And that your data is definitely in there?

Comment: Also, you don't need the duplicates in `AND RubricID in('1','1','1','1','1','1','6')` - just `AND RubricID in('1','6')` should do the job. And I would imagine you don't want quotes around the numbers, if you're saving them as Number types, and not strings/characters?

Comment: Actually my task is to get the all the IndicatorText for IndicatorID=13 and RubricID=1, IndicatorID=25 and RubricID=1...so on.. I want the text where both the IndicatorID and rubricId is matching. I have all the values in the database which I need.

Comment: Ah - different altogether! But I see you already have an answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

The two IN conditions are evaluated individually.

To check both values at once, you could concatenate them so that you have a single string to compare:

```sql
SELECT IndicatorText
FROM MyTable
WHERE IndicatorID || ',' || RubricID IN (
        '13,1', '25,1', '64,1', '52,1', '13,1', '25,1', '328,6')
```

However, doing this operation on the column values prevents the query optimizer from using indexes, so this query will be slow if the table is big.
To allow optimizations, create a temporary table with the desired values, and join that with the original table:

```sql
SELECT IndicatorText
FROM MyTable
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT 13 AS IndicatorID, 1 AS RubricID UNION ALL
              SELECT 25,                1             UNION ALL
              SELECT 64,                1             UNION ALL
              SELECT 52,                1             UNION ALL
              SELECT 13,                1             UNION ALL
              SELECT 25,                1             UNION ALL
              SELECT 328,               6)
```